# visual studio 2015, android command 'run-as' failed

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, debugging, cross-platform

The environments: windows 10(home, pro), visual studio 2015(community, professional) all combination.

Start visual studio 2015 update 1, new project, Native-Activity Application(Android), thus make default android native app. Build solution and start debugging. Then such error message is presented:

[image: Error message].

Unable to start debugging. Android command 'run-as' failed. Package 'com.Android1' is unknown.

I googled, but cannot find how to solve. What I missed? How to set up my environments, or fix something?

Comment: I formated disk, reinstall windows 10, and also install visual studio 2015 update 1.

Comment: I han exactly the same error in Visual Studio 2017 on all my 3 android devices at home...

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this is that you must root your device and fix a file permission. You can try following the advice on the prompt (especially if rooting is not an option) but in some cases only a root will fix the issue.

Once you have rooted your device open an adb shell and run the following:

```
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
chmod 4750 /system/bin/run-as
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

This fixes the setuid permission so that the run-as process is granted access based on the owner of the file (i.e. root).

Comment: If you have **root**, you don't need **run-as**, do you...?

Comment: but non-root things like visual studio and delphi, which use run-as (via adb) to attach their gdb debug sessions, do need it.

Comment: I had the same problem on my Samsung J1 (SM-J100H). Tried everything! The only way was to root the device and to use those 3 lines above. Thank you James!

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, trying to start debugging on VS2015, I got a different error, much less verbose than in the attached screenshot:

run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted

Based on the contents of the attached screenshot above, I tried 'initializing' / factory resetting the device using [Samsung's Smart Switch](http://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/) and it actually fixed the 'run-as' issue I was having.

Comment: Had the same issue on Samsung Galaxy S7 edge, i reset my device via  Samsung's Smart Switch (installed it on mac) and run-as command works now.

Comment: How do you reset the device with Smart switch?

Comment: A little more detail than a link to the page where you are shown some vague information about how to copy data from your old sammy phone to your new one, please?

Comment: In the Smart Switch software, there was an option to 'initialize' the device in one of the sub-menus, hopefully this option is still available in the latest software version - I didn't need to use the software anymore after resolving this issue on my phone.

Comment: My Samsung S5 debugged fine, my new S8 not, I see reports here of S6 and S7 being problematic. I have tried all the workarounds, nothing has helped my S8. Does anyone know if the problem still continues with the S9? I'm definitely going to be trying to look for a device that does not have this issue at all when my contract becomes due again.

Answer (score 0):

Down load it from Samsung, kies.  You will see an option to download the smart switch  Click the link in the previous answer...