# android studio 3.0 Device Explorer - run as: could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0, android-device-explorer

i migrate to android studio 3.0. i hear feature of new device explorer in android studio 3.0. but when i connect my android phone (Samsung Note 4 - N910C) i cant see the data\data package sub folder like database folder in device explorer. but when use android emulator i didn't have problem and can see package sub folder for same package. how can i solve this?

[image: Samsung N910C Device Explorer]

[image: Android Emulator Device Explorer]

Comment: same problem here. How to fix it?

Comment: Try to connect different phone. I try this with Samsung Galaxy j7 2017 and it doesn't worked. Then I try to connect Motorola Nexus 6 and it worked.

Comment: Any solution found so far ?

Comment: This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413667/run-as-could-not-set-capabilities-operation-not-permitted

Comment: same problem ... any one have solution ???

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like there's a bug in ADB's `run-as` command. According to [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37093233#comment53), `'run-as' failed. Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted` means Android Studio couldn't set elevated privs to read the contents of the app's directory.

Comments on the bug suggest Samsung regularly breaks the feature on their devices.

Answer (score 3):

### `data/data` Not Accessible

According to the [Android Studio docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) the `data/data` directory is not accessible in the Device File Explorer:

> Note: Not all files on a hardware device are visible in the Device File Explorer. For example, in the data/data/ directory, entries corresponding to apps on the device that are not debuggable cannot be expanded in the Device File Explorer.

Comment: _"entries corresponding to apps on the device that are not debuggable"_ means that if an app is debuggable then the device file explorer can access its data/data

Comment: @CliffBurton That's what I thought as well. However, using a DEBUG build on a real device still does not allow me to access the `data/data` directory. I've only been able to access the `data/data` directory through Device File Explorer on an emulator.

Comment: If your device is a Samsung then there is some bug in a OS build they released (API 24 probably), can't find the source now.

Comment: @CliffBurton Interesting. My device is a Samsung. Tab Active 1 and 2, generally. I'll have to try it with a non-Samsung device and see if it works.